# Different Application class per build variant crashes on some devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've modified my `build.gradle` to use different `Application` classes based on build-variant (`debug` / `release`).

I've added two `WrapperApplication` classes one in folder "`debug`", and the second in folder "`release`", both classes extend some base `Application` class.

In `AndroidManifest` I point to `com.my.package.WrapperApplication` and it indeed uses the correct one.
When releasing a test apk to Play, I got a pre-launch report that my new version crashed on 2 of the 13 devices tested (Moto G and Moto X).

Would love to know why is it crashing, and if something is wrong in the build, how is it working for me and for the other 11 test devices tested.

Here's the stack I received:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.my.package, PID: 16348
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.my.package.WrapperApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.my.package; is package not installed?
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4398)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.my.package; is package not installed?
    at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:376)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:329)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
    ... 11 more
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Previously we used the following method, but using the variant-specific folders is cleaner for our build system, so we'd love to switch to it.

Previous method:

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:name="${application}"
    ... />
```

build.gradle:

```
debug {
    manifestPlaceholders = [application:".Application1"]
}
release {
    manifestPlaceholders = [application: ".Application2"]
}
```

Comment: Do you also change package name for release?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I have 4 build-variants: debug/release and flavor1/flavor2. The package name is different per flavor not per build-type.

Comment: Ok, don't know the reason, but what we usually do - have one main app and change variant logic by overriding methods in base or injecting different strategies classes

Comment: We indeed used a different build method until now, but i would like to switch to this new one instead, see my edit above

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what is the reason for the issues. But we are doing a different approach:

1. We have base `Application` with  common functionality and it also contains protected methods for future behaviour modification:

   ```
   public class MyApp extends application {
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           initLogging();
       }

       protected void initLogging() {}
   }
   ```
2. We create another app in flavour or build configuration source folder and override behaviour:

   ```
   public class DebugMyApp extends MyApp {
       @Override
       protected void initLogging() {
           //init Stetho
       }
   }
   ```
3. We also create another `AndroidManifest.xml` in flavour or build configuration source folder where we override application name:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest
       package="com.philips.pins.ugrow"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   ​
       <application
           android:name=".DebugMyApp"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           tools:replace="android:name,android:label">

           <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity"/>
       </application>        ​
   </manifest>
   ```

Sure extension of the app is not necessary and you can define two different app classes but just correctly define them in manifest files.

Comment: That's pretty similar to our previous implementation, the only difference is that instead of overriding the application name via a manifest file, we used a manifestPlaceholders variable ${application}. I've tried switching back to this method, but I still got the same crash in the Play pre-launch tests on an HTC One. Still no idea why.